# Problems to use the variables in methods

Tags: java

I am getting an error when am trying to get the variables in the If else if statements any help will do thanks here is the program

```
public class Info {

    public static void main(String [] args){


        char f,F,c,C,h,H;

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter employee num");
        int e_num=input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter employee first name");
        String e_fname=input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter employee surname");
        String e_sname=input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter employee code C or c,H or h and F or f");
        char e_code = input.next().charAt(0);



        if(e_code=='f' || e_code=='F') {
        System.out.print("Enter employee salary: ");
        double salary=input.nextDouble();
             e_code=calGrossF();
        }

            else if(e_code=='c'||e_code=='C'){
            e_code=calGrossC();
            }

            else if(e_code=='h'|| e_code=='H'){
                e_code=calGrossH();
            }





       }//end of main 

    public static void calGrossF(int f, int F){




    }//end of Gross(F)
    public static char calGrossC(){

    }// end of Gross(C)

    public static char calGrossH();{
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile, you know that, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your code currently has several syntax errors.

- Your methods `calGrossC()` and `calGrossH()` have to return a `char` according to the declaration. Currently they just return nothing.
- This code `e_code=calGrossF();` expects `calGrossF()` to return a `char` as well. Currently it is declared to return `void`.
- You did not import the class `Scanner` (probably just not in the code sample).
- `callGross()` expects two `int` parameters. You gave none in `e_code=calGrossF();`.

All those errors are pointed out by the Java compiler. Just get through your error messages one by one and correct the code accordingly.

Not really syntax, but wanted to note it here:

- You declare a bunch of variables at the start (`f,F,c,C,h,H`), but never use them.

Here is a corrected code (just placeholders on several occasions):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Info {
  public static void main(String [] args){


    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter employee num");
    int e_num=input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter employee first name");
    String e_fname=input.next();
    System.out.print("Enter employee surname");
    String e_sname=input.next();
    System.out.print("Enter employee code C or c,H or h and F or f");
    char e_code = input.next().charAt(0);

    if(e_code=='f' || e_code=='F') {
      System.out.print("Enter employee salary: ");
      double salary=input.nextDouble();
      e_code=calGrossF( 0, 0 );
    }

    else if(e_code=='c'||e_code=='C'){
      e_code=calGrossC();
    }

    else if(e_code=='h'|| e_code=='H'){
      e_code=calGrossH();
    }
  }//end of main 

  public static char calGrossF(int f, int F){
      return 'F';
  }//end of Gross(F)

  public static char calGrossC(){
      return 'C';
  }// end of Gross(C)

  public static char calGrossH(){
      return 'H';
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me how to get the input inside one of the methods to get a monthly user salary...the program has to ask for ur salary plus tax ur sal if its above 1000

Comment: @KernDennis Is this homework? It seems you have not understood some basic coding concepts. I wont do all your work. Just Google for method calls in Java.

Answer (score 0):

First of all u have public static void calGrossF(int f, int F) as "void"
and u are storing its value in e_code
and also no arguments is being passed in the calling

Comment: i know am to do the calculation in a method when they user type one of the following char. but am getting errors trying to run it like F is for monthly employees

Comment: am getting missing javadoc

Answer (score 0):

```
//Method Statement
public char calGrossF(String name, int emp_num, double gross_sal, double fix_sal, double   
                      ded, double net_pay, double highest_sal, double lowest_sal, 
                      char ch)
{ 
    //return statement
    return calGrossF(name, emp_num, gross_sal, fix_sal, ded, net_pay, highest_sal, lowest_sal, ch);
}
```

Comment: i am getting an illegal expression how do i fix

Comment: i am getting illegal start of expression with this method statement how do i write over this method statement to get it right